# DIV stops refreshing when new database entry is made

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

**(UPDATE)**
So the problem isn't the database entries or the auto-refresh (sort of).
I've narrowed down the problem to a function in my index.php, that determines the color of the entry to be displayed. This function seems to be undefined when the auto-refresh reloads the included PHP pages.

So this is a very annoying issue that breaks the whole purpose of my web-based application. I have tried to troubleshoot it and can't figure out why it's refusing to work. My only guess is that the PHP/MySQL calls are not also being re-run when the refresh occurs, but that can't be true, because when I trigger event #3 listed below, it disappears just fine. It just doesn't update when an entry exists.

Div ID "unitsAvail" works fine, even when a new entry is created/deleted.

1) Refreshes perfectly fine when no entries exist.
2) Stops refreshing when a new database entry is created.
2b) Refreshing the page does not fix the auto-refresh.
3) Starts refreshing again when that entry is deleted, whether or not the page was reloaded.

***Note***: The refreshing php pages consist of an HTML table, and PHP code to call MySQL queries. They don't consist of any divs, or any other conflicting things.

***Note-2***: I added time stamp echos to each div, and Active/pending are indeed stopping their auto-refresh when new DB entries are made. Units Available continues to refresh perfectly fine, and the time stamp updates.

(I'm thinking it might be better to just put those PHP pages inside this page, and refresh the div content instead. How would I change my auto refresh to do that, if that's a better method? What do I change .load() to?)

```
    <script src="java/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        refreshActive();
    });

    function refreshActive() {
        $('#incActive').load('active.php', function() {
            setTimeout(refreshActive, 5000);
        });
        $('#incPending').load('pending.php', function() {
            setTimeout(refreshPending, 5000);
        });
        $('#unitsAvail').load('units.php', function() {
            setTimeout(refreshUnits, 5000);
        });
    }

    </script>
<body>
        <div id="fixed">

            <? include ("topmenu.php"); ?>

            <div id="backpanel">   

                <div id="incActive">
                    <?
                    include "active.php";
                    ?>
                </div>

                <div id="incPending">
                    <?
                    include "pending.php";
                    ?>
                </div>

                <div id="unitsAvail">
                    <?
                    include "units.php";
                    ?>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be caused by the load method throwing an exception. You should add some error handling to assist with debugging the issue.

Try using this to catch for any errors:

```
$('#incActive').load('active.php', function( response, status, xhr ) {
    if ( status == "error" ) {
        var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
        $( "#error" ).html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
    }
    else{
        setTimeout(refreshActive, 5000);
    }
);
```

Comment: Just did the test, and it errors to the div where the incident belongs. AKA, if a unit is assigned and it's active, then ACTIVE errors and PENDING is fine. If there's no units assigned, then it's opposite. If there's no incidents, both work. If there's one incident with a unit assigned and a 2nd incident with no units assigned, active errors but pending works fine.

Comment: I typically opt for using AJAX rather than the load method but, at the moment you're calling the setTimeout for each of the load methods

it might be worth just removing them and sticking just one setTimeout at the end of the refreshActive function.

Comment: I made a stupid. I just realized there's a php "error_log", and it says a function that I'm trying to use in those pages is not defined. It's a function that's only called when an incident is active or pending. Hence the issue!

I'm updating the question, but the problem is, a color determining function in the original page (index.php) is undefined once the page loads and the autofresh is being called.

Comment: Solved. I added some "function_exists()" checks to the master database.php file, and it now works flawlessly. Thanks for rubber ducking!